# resilience4j circuit breaker fails to open

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I am implementing a new method that we want protected with a circuit breaker and I'm following the same pattern as works on another method and yet it isn't working.

```java
  @Timed("data")
  @CircuitBreaker(name = "data")
  @Retry(name = "data")
  @TimeLimiter(name = "data")
  public void data() {
    try {
      doSomething();
    catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getClass().toString());
      throw e;
    }
}
```

I am then calling that method in a loop without a mock back end started so that every call fails and the circuit breaker should open, but it is not.

The output shows the exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException

I have it configured as:

```yaml
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      data:
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 1000
        minimum-number-of-calls: 6
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 3
  retry:
    retryAspectOrder: 2
    instances:
      data:
        max-attempts: 2
        retryExceptions:
          - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException
          - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException
  timelimiter:
    instances:
      data:
        timeoutDuration: 100ms
```

What would cause it not to open?

resilience4j 2.0.2
spring cloud 3.0.0
JDK 17
OS X 14.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, there was a mock bean being created and it was blocking the annotations from even being applied.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).